# Ubuntu Touch - Wifi - Sound - Stuff

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I recently installed Ubuntu Touch on my LG Nexus 4 and have followed all the steps.

At first, it seemed to be working perfectly well. Ubuntu booted, and was just as I expected it to be. Then I realized Wifi didn't work.

Next I noticed sound doesn't work either (from music app, phone app, etc.)

I can't install external apps either, and all I can do between my Linux Machine (computer) and my phone is access the phone's terminal through adb shell.

I have no idea where to start, from installing wifi, getting the sound to work, and getting the screen brightness to stay the way it is set whenever I switch off the phone and turn it back on.

Regarding the Wifi problem, I have read a few posts telling me to flash a radio.img from Android 4.3. I have no idea what that means, and if that is a necessary step I need guidance with it.

Thank-you, any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Closevoters, who are closing this as "unclear", please atleast leave a comment to let the OP know what he needs to do. As it's currently written, I think it gives a proper account of what the situation is. The only problem is that the OP might know how to troubleshoot this and as such he has not given any account of any troubleshooting that he might have done himself. Please let him know what he needs to do before voting to close the question. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Radio images for android 4.3 can be found [here](https://www.copy.com/s/JniBu/4.3%20files%20%28mako%29).

Download only the radio image and flash it. To flash it, copy radio.img to your device, reboot to BOOTLOADER and run the following command:

```
fastboot flash radio (radioimagename).img
```

(radioimage name is the name of the file you just downloaded and copied to your device)

Reboot again to Ubuntu after flashing the image. Everything should work. It did for me.